# Windows cmd: How to find and kill .bat file that was run and hidden with wscript?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, kill, wsh

I was playing with running a Turntable.fm bot, and I wanted to run it on my local machine's Nodejs installation, but not show the cmd window. So I ended up using a vbs script to hide the window:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

And then my .bat file looks like this:

```
.\node.exe .\Turntable-API\bots\carlin.js
```

That's it. Pretty simple. I created a shortcut file in Windows that then ran this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe "C:\ttbot\invisible.vbs" "C:\ttbot\ttbot.bat"
```

The issue now is that I have no idea how to find or kill the process that was started. When I try to look in my task manager, there's no wscript.exe, or cmd.exe, or node.exe, or invisible.vbs, or ttbot.bat running process of any sort. When I try running the .bat file in cmd, it doesn't close immediately, so I assume it needs manual shutdown of some sort. What should I do?

Comment: Simplest solution: reboot the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), search for any of the processes that you mentioned above incase the processes are running under an existing process, find that, then you can kill yours.

If it doesn't show up in Process Explorer the likelyhood is the script isn't running or it ended after execution, possibly because of an error. Try running without the vbscript to make sure everything is ok.